# how do i select a element with a attribute having special curly brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a html button, like below. it will have a attribute

```
<button class="first-button" data-content='{8C2E25C4-5E4F-484C-97D0-F42305F30E19}'> my content</button>
```

on click of this button i need to get that attribute and make a attribute selector out of it, for another element with a different class and same attribute

```
<button class="second-button" data-content='{8C2E25C4-5E4F-484C-97D0-F42305F30E19}'> my content</button>
```

i tried jquery attribute selector and that didn't work

```
$('data-content=8C2E25C4-5E4F-484C-97D0-F42305F30E19')
```

i am open to a JS or jQuery fix

Comment: Why was this re-opened? It's a very common duplicate.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The dupe was how to select a data attribute, not how to select a data attribute with special characters. Also I had an answer which was more up to date than the dupes I could find

Comment: There aren't special characters if you simply wrap the value in quotes, which is what the solution in the dupe explained. *Edit* - and @Swati's answer below does.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like below :

```js
$('button[data-content="{8C2E25C4-5E4F-484C-97D0-F42305F30E19}"]').addClass("active")
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="first-button" data-content='{8C2E25C4-5E4F-484C-97D0-F42305F30E19}'> my content</button>

<button class="second-button" data-content='{8C2E25C4-5E4F-484C-97D0-F42305F30E19}'> my content</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `[]` for [attribute selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) and will need a wildcard operator in selector since the value has `{}`

```js
$('[data-content*=8C2E25C4-5E4F-484C-97D0-F42305F30E19]').css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="first-button" data-content='{8C2E25C4-5E4F-484C-97D0-F42305F30E19}'> my content</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to quotes is [jQuery.escapeSelector](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/) or [CSS.escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape)

```js
const data = CSS.escape("{8C2E25C4-5E4F-484C-97D0-F42305F30E19}")
$(`button[data-content=${data}]`).addClass("active")
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="first-button" data-content='{8C2E25C4-5E4F-484C-97D0-F42305F30E19}'> my content</button>

<button class="second-button" data-content='{8C2E25C4-5E4F-484C-97D0-F42305F30E19}'> my content</button>
```